# Undefined data while loading from CSV for specific columns in D3

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am trying to read data from a csv file, and I want to store the data of each column in an array as in the code below. The problem that I get and I didn't know how to fix is that all the values are defined inside the brackets, but once I try to deal with the arrays else where, the data is undefined. Any ideas about what is going wrong? 
My version of D3 is v3.

```
<script>

var computerid = [];
var timestamp = [];
var percentage = [];

d3.csv("cpu-util.csv", function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        timestamp[i] = data[i].timestamp;
        computerid[i] = data[i].Computer_ID; 
        percentage[i] = data[i].Percentage;
        console.log(computerid[i]); //prints value
        console.log(timestamp[i]);
        console.log(percentage[i]);

    }
});

console.log(computerid[1]); //here, it prints undefined although inside the loop it prints values
```

Part of the csv file:

Computer_ID, timestamp, value, Percentage

1, 01-07-11 0:00, 0.8, 8

Comment: There is not enough information to provide an answer for this question. Please consider providing more information.

Comment: I have updated the question after figuring out somethings. The problem is that my values are defined inside the loop, but outside it, the values are not defined.

Comment: Yes the scope of the variable could be a major issue. In JS, the variable scope would be defined based on where it is declared.

Comment: It wasn't declared inside any function, all the arrays are global variables.

Comment: Could you post a part of the csv file as well. To see the data structure.

Comment: Based on the above code the array `computerid` is scoped within the function and is not a global variable. Hence when you are outside the function it will show as undefined because it was not declared outside the function.

Comment: Actually I forgot to paste the part where I declared the arrays, I think they are global.

Comment: Ah I see, so they are globally defined. But now we come to asynchronous code. JS runs in asynchronous manner. Read more about it here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript . That is possibly the reason why you are seeing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Oh I see now, I didn't know about the asynchronous behavior. Thank you all!

Comment: There is also additional problems with your code which I will highlight below based on the CSV data you have provided.

Comment: Hi @MahaAlrasheed I have provided some tips which will help you get started below. Hopefully it helps. Please mark as answer if you feel it provides enough information to get started at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV data needs to be in the correct format. There are a few unnecessary spaces which makes it difficult to parse as it includes the spaces in the header names on the basis of which it keeps the property names in the objects.

**cpu-util.csv** should be

```
Computer_ID,timestamp,value,Percentage
1,01-07-11 0:00,0.8,8
```

In addition d3.js parses the data keeping the header labels. therefore `computerid` array should be filled using the `Computer_ID` property of the data. Thus your code should be something like:

```
<script>
   var timestamp = [],
       computerid = [],
       percentage = [];

 d3.csv("cpu-util.csv", function(data) {
   console.log(data); //see the data structure
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        timestamp[i] = data[i].timestamp; //use the property names.
        computerid[i] = data[i].Computer_ID; 
        percentage[i] = data[i].Percentage;
        console.log(computerid[i]);
        console.log(timestamp[i]);
        console.log(percentage[i]);
    }
     console.log(computerid[0]); //this will appear as it is within the function and 
                                 //the array is filled by the time this line is run
  });

  console.log(computerid[0]); //this will be undefined due to the asynchronous nature of javascript. 
                              //This line of code runs before the for loop within the function
</script>
```

If you see the console log, the `console.log(computerid[0])` will appear first in the log before the other three in the function, due to the asynchronous nature of javascript. There are ways in which you can chain functions to make them synchronous using either Async/Await or Promises.

Also d3.js parses all the information as strings. So number values such as `Percentage` would need to be converted to number data types using a function. Just keep this in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about this asynchronous behavior. Again, thanks!

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you are happy with the answer and also up vote it if you like it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers